# Text Selection Title Bugs

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure what's causing this, it is nowhere else in my app except when i select text from an Alert Dialog...

[image: 1]

Usually the Select Text Title  looks normal but this happens from using EditText inside Alert Dialog.

Here's the normal Text Select

[image: 2]

Any solutions to Edit Text inside an Alert Dialog ...

Any information on why this is happening would be great, i can not find any documentation on Customizing or even Changing that Selection Title etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the text selection actionMode background color, use the below in your style:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/yourcolor</item>
```